# Ctrl-L does not clear the screen in cygwin/bash/mintty

Tags: bash, cygwin, mintty

I am using bash and mintty.  Ctrl-L does not clear the screen like it should:

```
0920:~$ ^L
-bash: $'\f': command not found
```

I get the same error if I've ssh-ed into a linux box via my cygwin mintty.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help developing software. You should consider asking this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/.

Comment: When this happens what does `bind -q clear-screen` output?

Comment: `clear-screen is not bound to any keys.` is the output

Comment: I use ctrl-l to clear the screen all the time in Mintty & cygwin. It's not a cygwin issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with your readline mappings in /etc/inputrc or ~/.inputrc.  try adding this:

"\C-l": clear-screen